# Paypal Adaptive Payments Fee Calculation

Tags: paypal

How does Paypal calculate the fees to apply to each receiver in case of a chained payment done with the Adatprive Payment API?

I'm intrested in the case where the primary receiver is the one who pays all the fees. Is the fee calculated on the total amount payed by the sender or is it a sum of the fees calculated on each aomount in which the transaction is split? The result can be very different because of the fixed .30 paypal charges on each transaction.

And how does this apply to microtransactions?

Answer (score 2):

There are some worked examples on this site:

https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/adaptive-payment-fee-calculation-analysis

I have no idea about the quality of the examples, I just stumbled across it while googling. However, it looks like the primary receiver can simply pay the sum of the fees that each party would otherwise be liable for.

Comment: nothing display in given link except y. Can you please put proper link in your answer.